# Proof check: if for any two vertices the degree sum is $n-1$ then $G$ is connected

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

If a simple graph $G$ has $n$ vertices and for any two distinct vertices $x,y$, the sum of the degrees of $x,y$ is $n-1$, then $G$ is connected.

PF: Suppose $x,y$ are not adjacent and they share no neighbor, then there are at least $n+1$ vertices.

This seems too simple for my class and I assume I did something wrong and I also assume I will feel silly once someone points it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds good; short and to the point.  You are actually proving something stronger.

Comment: Compare to the (far more interesting) Ore's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem

Comment: OK So I just realized that it should say "the sum of the degrees of $x,y$ is at least $n-1$ " in the problem statement. But that actually does not change anything right?

Comment: It is still ok @hardmath ?

Comment: Sure, it is still a sound argument.  You are actually showing that such a graph has diameter at most two, that the shortest path between any pair of points has at most two steps.

Comment: Right. That is what I wrote. Ty again.